# Drawing an ellipse inside a pgfplots semilog axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw an ellipse inside a semi-logarithmic `pgfplots` axis. The ellipse axes should be parallel to the coordinate axes, but depending on the radii I choose, the ellipse appears rotated.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymode=log]
  \addplot coordinates{
    (0,10) (1,300) (2,3347) (3,5000)
  };
  \draw 
  (axis cs:1,300) ellipse [
    x radius = 1, y radius = 10];   
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: screenshot of pgfplots output]

How can I align the ellipse with the coordinate axes, so that they are parallel to the ellipse axes?

Comment: Which version of pgfplots do you have?

Comment: @percusse Log file says `document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}`. So version 1.9, I guess.

Comment: Can you update to the newest version (currently 1.12 but 1.11 is also fine)?

Comment: @percusse With a local installation, maybe. I can try tomorrow.

Comment: @percusse just FYI, I get the same result with 1.12. I think this may be a bug. Some changes were introduced (v1.5.1 IIRC) to handle this problem in normal axes and maybe (semi-)log was missed or affected in some way.

Comment: Adding `rotate=-45` will get the horizontal ellipse, but that only works for your particular radii. found by trial and error. I know it's not a good solution, but if you need it now it will get you by.

Comment: @PaulGessler I get something else with 1.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule, I try to only do normal tikz AFTER \end{axis}.  Instead I save coordinates for use later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm}

\newlength{\rx}
\newlength{\ry}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymode=log]
  \addplot coordinates{
    (0,10) (1,300) (2,3347) (3,5000)
  };
  \coordinate (Center) at (axis cs:1,300);
  \coordinate (Radius) at (axis cs:2,3000);% x+1, y*10 relative to Center
  \end{axis}
  \pgfextractx{\rx}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{Radius}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{Center}{center}}}%
  \pgfextracty{\ry}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{Radius}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{Center}{center}}}%
  \draw (Center) ellipse [x radius = \rx, y radius = \ry]; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ellipse]