# Elongate side of a tikz ellipse or circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm hoping to make a few examples for my lecture slides that require generating some contour lines.

Is there a simple way to elongate one side of a tikz ellipse so that I can generate contours that look something like the following:[image]

Comment: The easiest way to do a contour plot is to load pgfplots and actually do a contour plot.  After the axis environment ends, you can tie additional tikz drawings using preset named coordinates.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228711/drawing-an-ellipse-inside-a-pgfplots-semilog-axis (somewhat related).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want a cartoon, you could try this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \X in {1,1.2,1.4,1.6}
{\draw[dashed] plot[smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(0,\X) (\X,0) (0,-\X) (-\X/2,0)};
}
\node[ellipse,minimum width=0.9cm,minimum height=2.8cm,draw,rotate=15] 
(elli) at (-0.5,1){};
\draw[-latex] (elli.center) -- (0.5,0.31)
node[below=0.3cm,align=center,anchor=north west]{$x+\Delta x_\mathrm{nsd}$\\
$x+\Delta x_\mathrm{nt}$};
\draw[fill=white] (elli.center) circle(1pt) node[right]{$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]