# Creating a tube plot from external data with pgfplots and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have the following `MWE`

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{
T1 T3 v11   v12 v13
0   0 0.66582 0.76 0.63
1   .000125 0.66582 0.76    0.63
2   .00025 0.66582  0.76    0.63
3   .000375 0.66582 0.76    0.63
4   .0005 0.66582   0.76    0.63
5   .000625 0.66582 0.76    0.63
6   .00075 0.66582  0.76    0.63
7   .000875 0.66582 0.76    0.63
8   .001 0.66582    0.76    0.63
9   .001125 0.66582 0.76    0.63
}\dummydata
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-4:4,
    samples y=0
]
{
    \addplot3[mark = none, color = green] table [x =T1, y =T3, z=v11]
      {\dummydata};
          \addplot3[mark = none, color = red] table [x =T1, y =T3, z=v12]
      {\dummydata};
          \addplot3[mark = none, color = blue] table [x =T1, y =T3, z=v13]
      {\dummydata};

}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with which I can create:

[image]

However, now what I am trying to do is to create a tube-like region around the `solid-red` line using the information (data) of `solid-blue and -green`, respectively.
Such that final plot will be somehthing like this:

[image]

(You can ignore the `gray-rectangular semi-transparent` plane). Any help is appreciated.

Now as per @marmot suggestion, a more complicated data-set where I wish to achieve the tube-like area:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{
tm,xm,xmd,xpd,ym,ymd,ypd
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0.04,0,0,0,0,0,0
0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0
0.12,0.34111,-2.4039,3.0861,-0.51786,-3.8303,2.7946
0.16,0.31078,-2.4179,3.0395,-0.54815,-3.9037,2.8074
0.2,0.32704,-2.4167,3.0707,-0.57982,-3.9058,2.7461
0.24,0.26665,-2.4367,2.97,-0.70117,-3.9647,2.5624
0.28,0.21992,-2.283,2.7228,-0.86952,-3.9877,2.2486
0.32,0.16058,-2.1158,2.437,-0.96921,-3.8313,1.8929
0.36,0.015983,-1.9724,2.0043,-1.0393,-3.6891,1.6105
0.4,-0.052178,-1.767,1.6626,-1.1558,-3.5265,1.2149
0.44,-0.12252,-1.5715,1.3265,-1.1154,-3.2262,0.99543
0.48,-0.15534,-1.3355,1.0248,-1.09,-2.9273,0.74723
0.52,-0.15089,-1.1588,0.85702,-1.0373,-2.7046,0.63006
0.56,-0.13807,-1.0788,0.80265,-0.96654,-2.4969,0.56384
0.6,-0.088093,-0.97758,0.80139,-0.90801,-2.3491,0.5331
0.64,-0.069781,-0.94086,0.80129,-0.89427,-2.3047,0.5162
0.68,-0.020531,-0.94687,0.90581,-0.818,-2.2231,0.58707
0.72,-0.027254,-0.96119,0.90668,-0.83075,-2.173,0.51149
0.76,-0.031288,-0.94815,0.88558,-0.82597,-2.2118,0.55987
0.8,-0.031409,-0.91782,0.855,-0.80136,-2.1164,0.51368
0.84,-0.063101,-0.84579,0.71959,-0.82437,-2.0932,0.44447
0.88,-0.09426,-0.80363,0.61511,-0.81774,-2.0294,0.39393
0.92,-0.12187,-0.71312,0.46938,-0.82512,-1.9138,0.26358
0.96,-0.13254,-0.63217,0.36709,-0.83908,-1.8382,0.16004
1,-0.12502,-0.64794,0.3979,-0.8046,-1.709,0.099775
1.04,-0.11963,-0.55243,0.31316,-0.8349,-1.6507,-0.019066
1.08,-0.1045,-0.58747,0.37847,-0.83788,-1.6403,-0.035508
1.12,-0.062444,-0.56731,0.44242,-0.78585,-1.4928,-0.078868
1.16,-0.079204,-0.6093,0.4509,-0.8005,-1.5141,-0.086878
1.2,-0.084476,-0.60549,0.43653,-0.80424,-1.5102,-0.098265
1.24,-0.082068,-0.5689,0.40476,-0.79587,-1.4862,-0.10553
1.28,-0.099081,-0.57148,0.37332,-0.78828,-1.4717,-0.1049
1.32,-0.13329,-0.60353,0.33696,-0.81407,-1.4543,-0.17382
1.36,-0.096508,-0.47577,0.28276,-0.78266,-1.4171,-0.14827
1.4,-0.14497,-0.56515,0.27521,-0.81147,-1.3793,-0.24363
1.44,-0.12127,-0.51149,0.26894,-0.78772,-1.3515,-0.22388
1.48,-0.1217,-0.51802,0.27463,-0.78803,-1.3051,-0.271
1.52,-0.12173,-0.51559,0.27214,-0.79021,-1.2825,-0.29787
1.56,-0.10114,-0.51495,0.31267,-0.77804,-1.2414,-0.31463
1.6,-0.1014,-0.50952,0.30672,-0.76874,-1.1943,-0.34319
1.64,-0.11196,-0.48854,0.26461,-0.7622,-1.1585,-0.36586
1.68,-0.053825,-0.4586,0.35095,-0.71589,-1.108,-0.32376
1.72,-0.078095,-0.43485,0.27866,-0.73016,-1.0662,-0.39413
1.76,-0.080373,-0.47621,0.31547,-0.72842,-1.1203,-0.33655
1.8,-0.039621,-0.40915,0.3299,-0.68146,-1.0132,-0.34977
1.84,-0.062119,-0.43261,0.30837,-0.69357,-1.0315,-0.35569
1.88,-0.057911,-0.41945,0.30363,-0.67735,-1.0079,-0.34684
1.92,-0.053722,-0.40234,0.29489,-0.67227,-0.95972,-0.38482
1.96,-0.065276,-0.39114,0.26058,-0.68735,-0.94931,-0.42539
2,-0.037894,-0.39006,0.31428,-0.66806,-0.90303,-0.43309
2.04,-0.036814,-0.31968,0.24605,-0.66693,-0.89665,-0.4372
2.08,-0.038017,-0.35327,0.27724,-0.67016,-0.9178,-0.42253
2.12,-0.0097459,-0.29652,0.27703,-0.64795,-0.86252,-0.43338
2.16,-0.017039,-0.3108,0.27673,-0.64223,-0.86004,-0.42443
2.2,-0.010354,-0.3032,0.28249,-0.63579,-0.8435,-0.42808
2.24,-0.0075316,-0.2807,0.26564,-0.61478,-0.78884,-0.44073
2.28,-0.011665,-0.31125,0.28792,-0.60756,-0.75897,-0.45614
2.32,-0.031825,-0.32928,0.26563,-0.6092,-0.71376,-0.50465
2.36,0.00065694,-0.29614,0.29746,-0.5606,-0.70139,-0.41982
2.4,0.0043591,-0.30116,0.30988,-0.55409,-0.65516,-0.45303
2.44,0.00056132,-0.32006,0.32119,-0.54239,-0.64429,-0.44049
2.48,0.0080039,-0.31491,0.33092,-0.54615,-0.64203,-0.45027
2.52,0.017543,-0.29376,0.32884,-0.54204,-0.62597,-0.45812
2.56,0.043735,-0.25843,0.3459,-0.52438,-0.58751,-0.46125
2.6,0.053718,-0.2384,0.34583,-0.49305,-0.52909,-0.45702
2.64,0.046364,-0.20966,0.30239,-0.47018,-0.53222,-0.40814
2.68,0.079327,-0.20243,0.36109,-0.37582,-0.40642,-0.34523
2.72,0.072251,-0.20886,0.35336,-0.34565,-0.38803,-0.30328
2.76,0.051764,-0.2224,0.32593,-0.323,-0.37129,-0.27472
2.8,0.049093,-0.22782,0.32601,-0.25679,-0.30908,-0.2045
2.84,0.038224,-0.23386,0.31031,-0.23561,-0.29658,-0.17464
2.88,0.02659,-0.27056,0.32374,-0.196,-0.29468,-0.097316
2.92,0.003124,-0.31375,0.32,-0.17749,-0.27682,-0.078165
2.96,-0.0018435,-0.29729,0.2936,-0.16058,-0.27943,-0.041725
3,-0.006709,-0.39879,0.38537,-0.15632,-0.21252,-0.10013
3.04,-0.033639,-0.35582,0.28854,-0.15892,-0.24118,-0.076667
3.08,-0.032483,-0.38838,0.32341,-0.14021,-0.18432,-0.096106
3.12,-0.029824,-0.36757,0.30792,-0.11038,-0.15382,-0.066938
3.16,-0.037045,-0.38856,0.31447,-0.095147,-0.16009,-0.030209
3.2,-0.05167,-0.40226,0.29892,-0.06759,-0.11908,-0.016101
3.24,-0.049338,-0.39622,0.29754,-0.051711,-0.123,0.019576
3.28,-0.042641,-0.37827,0.29299,-0.028917,-0.13901,0.081174
3.32,-0.087298,-0.44836,0.27376,-0.034339,-0.11291,0.044231
3.36,-0.063621,-0.40711,0.27987,-0.0035416,-0.16211,0.15503
3.4,-0.056421,-0.4119,0.29906,0.019537,-0.087551,0.12663
3.44,-0.075507,-0.46623,0.31522,-0.013768,-0.15164,0.1241
3.48,-0.063827,-0.44935,0.3217,0.0064244,-0.11088,0.12373
3.52,-0.063597,-0.45513,0.32794,0.011473,-0.076058,0.099004
3.56,-0.050908,-0.45053,0.34871,0.03448,-0.045832,0.11479
3.6,-0.033273,-0.46869,0.40214,0.050067,-0.015407,0.11554
3.64,-0.066905,-0.44499,0.31118,0.017897,-0.067961,0.10375
3.68,-0.046271,-0.48794,0.39539,0.033531,-0.069233,0.1363
3.72,-0.05138,-0.45257,0.34981,0.05112,-0.029063,0.1313
3.76,-0.070642,-0.49432,0.35304,0.014393,-0.11913,0.14792
3.8,-0.070007,-0.47799,0.33798,0.030181,-0.093617,0.15398
3.84,-0.078997,-0.47921,0.32122,0.0099555,-0.13733,0.15724
3.88,-0.064307,-0.46206,0.33344,0.011714,-0.11396,0.13738
3.92,-0.068079,-0.46893,0.33277,0.018777,-0.09173,0.12928
3.96,-0.053161,-0.42124,0.31492,0.01825,-0.099128,0.13563
4,-0.022433,-0.49323,0.44836,0.037708,-0.02134,0.096756
4.04,-0.033149,-0.45834,0.39204,0.04793,-0.032419,0.12828
4.08,-0.041493,-0.47415,0.39117,0.040858,-0.021069,0.10278
4.12,-0.057713,-0.46698,0.35155,0.039439,-0.042223,0.1211
4.16,-0.054769,-0.44338,0.33385,0.048358,-0.047295,0.14401
4.2,-0.063519,-0.46221,0.33517,0.038351,-0.041262,0.11796
4.24,-0.063892,-0.44782,0.32004,0.036186,-0.068824,0.1412
4.28,-0.056123,-0.40631,0.29407,0.0476,-0.064233,0.15943
4.32,-0.094136,-0.45608,0.2678,0.015395,-0.083746,0.11454
4.36,-0.073154,-0.4461,0.29979,0.030337,-0.14479,0.20547
4.4,-0.050985,-0.42611,0.32414,0.06799,-0.017188,0.15317
4.44,-0.069921,-0.47383,0.33399,0.056972,-0.075461,0.1894
4.48,-0.05228,-0.46064,0.35608,0.083086,-0.0056697,0.17184
4.52,-0.05134,-0.45118,0.3485,0.096423,0.0019748,0.19087
4.56,-0.052724,-0.46209,0.35664,0.086379,-0.011513,0.18427
4.6,-0.043504,-0.50302,0.41601,0.080933,-0.015713,0.17758
4.64,-0.084016,-0.46078,0.29275,0.036149,-0.07109,0.14339
4.68,-0.05337,-0.4727,0.36596,0.051233,-0.075305,0.17777
4.72,-0.047571,-0.43556,0.34042,0.058992,-0.021999,0.13998
4.76,-0.076011,-0.486,0.33398,0.020806,-0.10033,0.14194
4.8,-0.06046,-0.46313,0.34221,0.052942,-0.049416,0.1553
4.84,-0.063963,-0.48172,0.3538,0.046092,-0.050885,0.14307
4.88,-0.05335,-0.48394,0.37724,0.066777,-0.038134,0.17169
4.92,-0.056813,-0.49169,0.37807,0.079715,-0.030218,0.18965
4.96,-0.053435,-0.43036,0.32349,0.089452,-0.027211,0.20611
5,-0.053848,-0.52124,0.41355,0.10071,-0.0093193,0.21073
5.04,-0.083567,-0.50769,0.34056,0.073753,-0.090077,0.23758
5.08,-0.07258,-0.45966,0.3145,0.08868,-0.05089,0.22825
5.12,0.00084803,-0.39465,0.39635,0.048857,-0.12497,0.22269
5.16,0.13554,-0.27892,0.55001,0.041207,-0.12962,0.21203
5.2,0.40825,-0.069637,0.88613,0.050071,-0.1298,0.22994
5.24,0.67117,0.21572,1.1266,0.048443,-0.10058,0.19747
5.28,1.0633,0.45878,1.6678,0.090288,-0.08581,0.26638
5.32,1.4693,0.80123,2.1374,0.089672,-0.070362,0.24971
5.36,1.7759,1.0413,2.5104,0.11808,-0.08123,0.31739
5.4,2.2478,1.4725,3.0231,0.18277,0.021067,0.34448
5.44,2.6068,1.7448,3.4688,0.19036,0.0073643,0.37336
5.48,2.909,2.0545,3.7635,0.19718,0.0052129,0.38915
5.52,3.2663,2.3967,4.136,0.20015,0.031327,0.36896
5.56,3.5597,2.6781,4.4413,0.20717,0.042911,0.37144
6.76,6.4335,6.1771,6.6899,0.24583,0.11987,0.37179
6.8,6.4503,6.2052,6.6953,0.24771,0.12392,0.3715
6.84,6.4881,6.2321,6.7441,0.25109,0.13723,0.36495
6.88,6.5094,6.2602,6.7585,0.24703,0.13902,0.35503
6.92,6.5216,6.2973,6.7459,0.25129,0.16407,0.33851
6.96,6.5899,6.3593,6.8205,0.25022,0.14516,0.35527
7,6.6188,6.4196,6.818,0.24323,0.19472,0.29175
7.04,6.6412,6.3826,6.8998,0.23618,0.14959,0.32277
7.08,6.6917,6.412,6.9713,0.24519,0.18214,0.30823
7.12,6.7147,6.3912,7.0383,0.2398,0.18131,0.2983
7.16,6.7315,6.3803,7.0827,0.24463,0.15948,0.32977
7.2,6.7522,6.381,7.1235,0.26291,0.16465,0.36116
7.24,6.7502,6.3647,7.1358,0.25668,0.11773,0.39564
7.28,6.7824,6.4031,7.1617,0.28356,0.14323,0.42389
7.32,6.7894,6.4244,7.1545,0.27849,0.12083,0.43615
7.36,6.8157,6.4514,7.18,0.27862,0.10427,0.45297
7.4,6.8482,6.5263,7.1701,0.30119,0.14656,0.45583
7.44,6.8305,6.4684,7.1927,0.29605,0.14886,0.44324
7.48,6.8442,6.4659,7.2226,0.30386,0.15869,0.44903
7.52,6.8506,6.4286,7.2727,0.30484,0.15302,0.45666
7.56,6.8496,6.4125,7.2867,0.29756,0.1237,0.47142
7.6,6.8548,6.4366,7.273,0.25163,0.14919,0.35408
7.64,6.8741,6.4435,7.3046,0.1238,-0.039884,0.28748
7.68,6.8937,6.5022,7.2853,-0.017529,-0.14808,0.11302
7.72,6.9162,6.5359,7.2964,-0.32985,-0.48445,-0.17526
7.76,6.9465,6.5946,7.2984,-0.59723,-0.69643,-0.49803
7.8,6.9923,6.6637,7.3208,-0.97282,-1.171,-0.77466
7.84,7.0541,6.7295,7.3786,-1.4468,-1.6747,-1.219
7.88,7.0898,6.7545,7.425,-1.7771,-2.0199,-1.5343
7.92,7.1271,6.7552,7.4989,-2.2983,-2.5595,-2.037
7.96,7.1138,6.6874,7.5402,-2.7553,-3.1106,-2.4001
8,7.0718,6.6872,7.4564,-3.0869,-3.4405,-2.7333
8.04,7.0063,6.5691,7.4436,-3.5022,-3.8674,-3.137
8.08,6.9727,6.5442,7.4012,-3.7816,-4.1216,-3.4416
8.12,6.9554,6.5244,7.3865,-4.1073,-4.5071,-3.7075
8.16,6.9803,6.5929,7.3678,-4.4256,-4.8657,-3.9854
8.2,7.0041,6.6295,7.3787,-4.6424,-5.0375,-4.2473
8.24,7.0188,6.656,7.3815,-4.8274,-5.2412,-4.4135
8.28,7.0472,6.6968,7.3976,-4.9368,-5.2982,-4.5754
8.32,7.0483,6.6807,7.4159,-5.0095,-5.2984,-4.7206
8.36,7.0263,6.6358,7.4167,-5.0906,-5.3505,-4.8308
8.4,7.0195,6.6356,7.4033,-5.1708,-5.4009,-4.9407
8.44,7.0289,6.6191,7.4388,-5.2772,-5.501,-5.0533
8.48,7.063,6.661,7.465,-5.4327,-5.6855,-5.1798
8.52,7.0909,6.6867,7.4952,-5.5987,-5.8348,-5.3625
8.56,7.1166,6.6788,7.5543,-5.8046,-6.1261,-5.4831
8.6,7.121,6.6979,7.5442,-5.996,-6.3047,-5.6872
8.64,7.0953,6.5918,7.5989,-6.1159,-6.4159,-5.816
8.68,7.0522,6.5205,7.5838,-6.2303,-6.5434,-5.9173
8.72,6.9995,6.437,7.5621,-6.2855,-6.5682,-6.0027
8.76,6.9611,6.3757,7.5465,-6.3131,-6.5813,-6.0448
8.8,6.8916,6.2743,7.509,-6.3218,-6.5595,-6.084
8.84,6.8692,6.2553,7.4831,-6.3418,-6.5496,-6.1341
8.88,6.8868,6.2735,7.5001,-6.3578,-6.5522,-6.1634
8.92,6.9582,6.3996,7.5168,-6.4474,-6.674,-6.2209
8.96,7.0188,6.4351,7.6026,-6.5521,-6.8008,-6.3035
9,7.1062,6.5974,7.615,-6.6711,-6.9728,-6.3694
9.04,7.1562,6.6706,7.6418,-6.8161,-7.0907,-6.5415
9.08,7.1891,6.7355,7.6427,-6.8684,-7.0917,-6.645
9.12,7.1411,6.6381,7.6441,-6.88,-7.116,-6.644
9.16,7.052,6.4883,7.6156,-6.8336,-7.0969,-6.5704
9.2,6.9774,6.3824,7.5724,-6.7699,-7.0076,-6.5321
9.24,6.9156,6.3152,7.5159,-6.7387,-6.9156,-6.5618
9.28,6.9542,6.4245,7.4839,-6.7725,-7.0108,-6.5343
9.32,7.0016,6.4507,7.5526,-6.834,-7.1523,-6.5156
9.36,7.169,6.6666,7.6715,-6.9756,-7.3914,-6.5597
9.4,7.2619,6.7704,7.7534,-7.0933,-7.5018,-6.6848
9.44,7.3342,6.9428,7.7256,-7.2009,-7.5759,-6.826
9.48,7.3422,6.9404,7.744,-7.2382,-7.559,-6.9175
9.52,7.3034,6.8612,7.7456,-7.2004,-7.4885,-6.9124
9.56,7.1462,6.5482,7.7443,-7.1165,-7.3986,-6.8344
9.6,7.0407,6.5134,7.5681,-7.0325,-7.2877,-6.7773
9.64,6.9497,6.3851,7.5143,-6.971,-7.1549,-6.7871
9.68,6.9977,6.4771,7.5182,-7.0397,-7.4102,-6.6691
9.72,7.0861,6.5399,7.6323,-7.1605,-7.6829,-6.638
9.76,7.267,6.8108,7.7231,-7.3677,-8.0191,-6.7163
9.8,7.4187,7.0903,7.7471,-7.5638,-8.2129,-6.9146
9.84,7.5155,7.222,7.8089,-7.6459,-8.262,-7.0297
9.88,7.4995,7.1265,7.8725,-7.6468,-8.2183,-7.0753
9.92,7.3399,6.8646,7.8151,-7.555,-8.0892,-7.0208
9.96,7.2109,6.6922,7.7296,-7.4577,-7.9734,-6.942
10,7.0758,6.592,7.5595,-7.3723,-7.7758,-6.9688
10.04,7.0355,6.6073,7.4638,-7.3607,-7.7956,-6.9257
10.08,7.0587,6.586,7.5315,-7.4092,-7.9834,-6.835
10.12,7.2429,6.7083,7.7774,-7.6065,-8.3659,-6.847
10.16,7.4034,6.9113,7.8955,-7.7812,-8.5842,-6.9781
10.2,7.5615,7.3003,7.8227,-7.9624,-8.7897,-7.1351
10.24,7.616,7.3577,7.8744,-8.0548,-8.8964,-7.2132
10.28,7.5448,7.1839,7.9057,-8.0201,-8.8291,-7.2111
10.32,7.387,6.8901,7.8838,-7.8865,-8.6371,-7.1359
10.36,7.2264,6.7905,7.6623,-7.7327,-8.4122,-7.0531
10.4,7.1643,6.7736,7.555,-7.6768,-8.3274,-7.0262
10.44,7.1903,6.7654,7.6152,-7.6918,-8.4264,-6.9571
10.48,7.3427,6.7498,7.9355,-7.8483,-8.7806,-6.916
10.52,7.4903,6.8832,8.0974,-8.0292,-9.0224,-7.0361
10.56,7.7234,7.2576,8.1892,-8.2671,-9.2216,-7.3127
10.6,7.84,7.4842,8.1958,-8.4146,-9.2455,-7.5838
10.64,7.8325,7.4521,8.2129,-8.4221,-9.216,-7.6283
10.68,7.686,7.2564,8.1155,-8.2886,-9.0407,-7.5364
10.72,7.5263,7.0998,7.9529,-8.0951,-8.8397,-7.3506
10.76,7.3631,6.9396,7.7865,-7.8994,-8.5654,-7.2334
10.8,7.219,6.7484,7.6896,-7.7601,-8.4708,-7.0494
10.84,7.2715,6.6986,7.8444,-7.8114,-8.6497,-6.9731
10.88,7.4858,6.7656,8.206,-8.0509,-9.0253,-7.0764
10.92,7.736,6.9685,8.5036,-8.3467,-9.2164,-7.4771
10.96,7.9589,7.3295,8.5883,-8.6155,-9.3578,-7.8732
11,8.0919,7.4751,8.7088,-8.7833,-9.4115,-8.155
11.04,8.0053,7.3923,8.6183,-8.7394,-9.3799,-8.0988
11.08,7.8173,7.176,8.4586,-8.5279,-9.1881,-7.8676
11.12,7.5877,6.9553,8.2201,-8.2838,-8.9086,-7.6591
11.16,7.4758,6.9209,8.0307,-8.136,-8.7648,-7.5073
11.2,7.4464,6.8011,8.0917,-8.077,-8.6354,-7.5186
11.24,7.6276,6.7951,8.46,-8.2437,-8.9473,-7.5401
11.28,7.8597,6.9583,8.7611,-8.4336,-9.1375,-7.7297
11.32,8.1823,7.2603,9.1043,-8.7751,-9.3313,-8.2188
11.36,8.3611,7.4759,9.2462,-8.926,-9.2665,-8.5856
11.4,8.3824,7.5894,9.1754,-8.9688,-9.3756,-8.562
11.44,8.1936,7.5055,8.8817,-8.786,-9.288,-8.2839
11.48,7.9719,7.3563,8.5875,-8.5793,-9.166,-7.9926
11.52,7.7549,7.1856,8.3243,-8.3558,-8.8653,-7.8462
11.56,7.6155,7.0069,8.2241,-8.1745,-8.6248,-7.7242
11.6,7.6205,6.9457,8.2954,-8.2028,-8.6084,-7.7971
11.64,7.8577,6.9545,8.7609,-8.3849,-9.0302,-7.7397
11.68,8.1678,7.0749,9.2608,-8.7006,-9.4053,-7.9959
11.72,8.3917,7.3443,9.439,-8.982,-9.5189,-8.4452
11.76,8.5678,7.6396,9.4961,-9.1095,-9.4504,-8.7686
11.8,8.4624,7.626,9.2989,-8.9957,-9.4007,-8.5907
11.84,8.3294,7.5415,9.1173,-8.8516,-9.38,-8.3232
11.88,8.091,7.3196,8.8624,-8.5691,-9.1187,-8.0194
11.92,7.9079,7.2791,8.5366,-8.3941,-8.96,-7.8282
11.96,7.8445,7.0898,8.5992,-8.3102,-8.8217,-7.7987
12,7.9816,7.0019,8.9613,-8.4754,-9.2098,-7.7411
12.04,8.1679,6.987,9.3489,-8.6768,-9.5306,-7.823
12.08,8.3604,7.132,9.5888,-8.9552,-9.8836,-8.0269
12.12,8.4423,7.3428,9.5419,-9.0546,-9.6396,-8.4696
12.16,8.5183,7.646,9.3906,-9.1469,-9.5624,-8.7314
12.2,8.4105,7.7887,9.0322,-9.058,-9.4954,-8.6206
12.24,8.2313,7.7486,8.7139,-8.8548,-9.3988,-8.3108
12.28,8.0632,7.6282,8.4981,-8.6484,-9.2335,-8.0632
12.32,7.8982,7.3276,8.4689,-8.4582,-9.1113,-7.8051
12.36,7.9176,7.1409,8.6943,-8.4585,-9.1423,-7.7747
12.4,8.0588,6.9721,9.1455,-8.573,-9.4289,-7.7171
12.44,8.3161,7.0408,9.5914,-8.801,-9.6024,-7.9996
12.48,8.5953,7.2536,9.9369,-8.9989,-9.6354,-8.3624
12.52,8.7016,7.5325,9.8708,-9.1714,-9.5738,-8.769
12.56,8.6841,7.6921,9.6761,-9.1068,-9.3105,-8.903
12.6,8.6335,7.8298,9.4371,-9.0789,-9.3712,-8.7866
12.64,8.4065,7.6868,9.1262,-8.8581,-9.2483,-8.4678
12.68,8.2158,7.6246,8.8071,-8.653,-9.1138,-8.1921
12.72,8.08,7.3868,8.7732,-8.5101,-8.9045,-8.1156
12.76,8.0294,7.1304,8.9284,-8.4587,-8.8631,-8.0542
12.8,8.1312,7.0364,9.226,-8.5674,-9.0251,-8.1098
12.84,8.316,7.0534,9.5785,-8.7166,-9.3139,-8.1194
12.88,8.4955,7.1897,9.8012,-8.8445,-9.3924,-8.2967
12.92,8.5834,7.4362,9.7307,-8.9613,-9.3424,-8.5802
12.96,8.6169,7.7417,9.492,-8.9791,-9.1952,-8.763
13,8.4831,7.8227,9.1435,-8.8585,-9.1409,-8.5761
13.04,8.331,7.7631,8.899,-8.6955,-9.0472,-8.3439
13.08,8.0345,7.6093,8.4597,-8.3997,-8.8241,-7.9752
13.12,7.8765,7.4636,8.2895,-8.22,-8.6407,-7.7993
13.16,7.7856,7.1466,8.4246,-8.1193,-8.3936,-7.8449
13.2,7.8842,6.9836,8.7847,-8.243,-8.5545,-7.9315
13.24,8.1421,6.9618,9.3223,-8.4929,-8.8825,-8.1033
13.28,8.4318,7.2089,9.6547,-8.7445,-9.2216,-8.2674
13.32,8.5441,7.3571,9.731,-8.8794,-9.2427,-8.5162
13.36,8.6136,7.7292,9.4981,-8.9508,-9.1558,-8.7458
13.4,8.4702,7.8355,9.1048,-8.8271,-9.1617,-8.4925
13.44,8.2577,7.7884,8.727,-8.6168,-9.0765,-8.157
13.48,8.0814,7.5981,8.5647,-8.4101,-8.8263,-7.9939
13.52,7.8933,7.3123,8.4744,-8.2215,-8.47,-7.973
15.36,7.2138,6.5296,7.898,-8.5991,-8.6488,-8.5493
15.4,7.1106,6.5327,7.6886,-8.6298,-8.9497,-8.3098
15.44,6.9851,6.4236,7.5467,-8.6449,-8.9982,-8.2915
15.48,6.8448,6.257,7.4326,-8.5407,-8.7818,-8.2996
15.52,6.7419,6.1343,7.3496,-8.5791,-8.7467,-8.4115
15.56,6.6545,5.865,7.444,-8.4884,-8.7791,-8.1977
15.6,6.548,5.5956,7.5005,-8.4138,-8.9103,-7.9174
15.64,6.4446,5.49,7.3993,-8.3434,-8.8305,-7.8563
15.68,6.3337,5.4411,7.2262,-8.3013,-8.7003,-7.9022
15.72,6.2438,5.5468,6.9408,-8.3073,-8.474,-8.1407
15.76,6.1374,5.6962,6.5787,-8.2497,-8.3804,-8.1191
15.8,6.0879,5.7563,6.4196,-8.2948,-8.5981,-7.9916
15.84,6.0485,5.7321,6.3649,-8.3143,-8.737,-7.8917
15.88,5.9958,5.6467,6.345,-8.2947,-8.6478,-7.9417
15.92,5.9272,5.4427,6.4118,-8.266,-8.4633,-8.0688
15.96,5.8753,5.2035,6.547,-8.2425,-8.5263,-7.9588
16,5.7818,4.9646,6.599,-8.1543,-8.6346,-7.674
16.04,5.6813,4.7773,6.5853,-8.0588,-8.5878,-7.5298
16.08,5.6191,4.8193,6.4189,-8.0331,-8.4484,-7.6179
16.12,5.6281,5.002,6.2541,-8.1211,-8.3452,-7.8969
16.16,5.7124,5.3256,6.0992,-8.2116,-8.3616,-8.0616
16.2,5.6929,5.4639,5.922,-8.2367,-8.6291,-7.8444
16.24,5.7247,5.3984,6.0509,-8.2925,-8.8279,-7.757
16.28,5.694,5.3375,6.0504,-8.2859,-8.7903,-7.7814
16.32,5.6315,5.213,6.0499,-8.2435,-8.67,-7.817
16.36,5.5642,4.9749,6.1535,-8.1976,-8.5188,-7.8764
16.4,5.4815,4.7513,6.2117,-8.1132,-8.5086,-7.7179
16.44,5.4316,4.6731,6.19,-8.0414,-8.4595,-7.6233
16.48,5.4079,4.6978,6.1179,-8.0198,-8.3218,-7.7178
16.52,5.3731,4.8915,5.8547,-8.0236,-8.1053,-7.9418
16.56,5.5056,5.2508,5.7605,-8.1507,-8.3439,-7.9574
16.6,5.5714,5.3066,5.8362,-8.2214,-8.7373,-7.7054
16.64,5.5832,5.2259,5.9406,-8.2499,-8.8658,-7.6339
16.68,5.587,5.1692,6.0049,-8.2355,-8.8264,-7.6445
16.72,5.5594,5.1322,5.9865,-8.2328,-8.6869,-7.7787
16.76,5.5387,4.9824,6.0949,-8.2001,-8.6205,-7.7797
16.8,5.4439,4.7606,6.1273,-8.1231,-8.5718,-7.6744
16.84,5.358,4.6073,6.1087,-8.0344,-8.4224,-7.6464
16.88,5.3622,4.7038,6.0206,-8.025,-8.2767,-7.7733
16.92,5.3469,4.8687,5.8251,-8.0623,-8.1119,-8.0127
16.96,5.3624,5.1224,5.6024,-8.0932,-8.3935,-7.793
17,5.4389,5.2731,5.6047,-8.1905,-8.7237,-7.6573
17.04,5.4783,5.1772,5.7793,-8.2555,-8.9358,-7.5751
17.08,5.4979,5.1699,5.8258,-8.2484,-8.9139,-7.5829
17.12,5.4437,5.0455,5.8419,-8.283,-8.8392,-7.7267
17.16,5.4542,4.897,6.0114,-8.2238,-8.6675,-7.7801
17.2,5.3769,4.7225,6.0313,-8.1619,-8.6314,-7.6923
17.24,5.284,4.5999,5.968,-8.0745,-8.4358,-7.7132
17.28,5.2305,4.657,5.804,-8.0153,-8.1969,-7.8337
17.32,5.2639,4.8379,5.69,-8.0564,-8.1557,-7.9572
17.36,5.2931,5.1229,5.4634,-8.1233,-8.5252,-7.7214
17.4,5.311,5.2578,5.3642,-8.1673,-8.72,-7.6146
17.44,5.3898,5.1694,5.6101,-8.2527,-8.9228,-7.5827
17.48,5.4423,5.168,5.7167,-8.3127,-8.9051,-7.7203
17.52,5.4021,4.973,5.8312,-8.2875,-8.8092,-7.7659
17.56,5.4159,4.8505,5.9813,-8.2791,-8.7201,-7.8382
17.6,5.3436,4.6918,5.9955,-8.1967,-8.6036,-7.7899
17.64,5.2599,4.5829,5.937,-8.0494,-8.4421,-7.6566
17.68,5.153,4.4728,5.8332,-7.819,-8.1809,-7.4571
17.72,5.0653,4.4931,5.6375,-7.623,-7.9002,-7.3458
17.76,5.0361,4.5722,5.4999,-7.3615,-7.634,-7.089
17.8,4.9857,4.7507,5.2207,-7.1503,-7.4999,-6.8007
17.84,5.015,4.8164,5.2136,-7.034,-7.5023,-6.5657
17.88,5.1345,4.9011,5.368,-6.9628,-7.5209,-6.4046
17.92,5.2402,4.8995,5.581,-6.9307,-7.4582,-6.4032
17.96,5.2999,4.8594,5.7405,-6.8847,-7.3514,-6.418
18,5.3246,4.7563,5.8929,-6.7857,-7.1467,-6.4246
18.04,5.2933,4.632,5.9546,-6.619,-6.9235,-6.3145
18.08,5.2382,4.5486,5.9279,-6.5053,-6.7718,-6.2388
18.12,5.1433,4.5943,5.6924,-6.3374,-6.4974,-6.1774
18.16,5.0859,4.6652,5.5066,-6.2045,-6.324,-6.085
18.2,5.0549,4.7084,5.4014,-6.1654,-6.4726,-5.8581
18.24,5.0822,4.7502,5.4142,-6.1253,-6.6257,-5.6248
18.28,5.0888,4.7149,5.4626,-6.1201,-6.6591,-5.5811
18.32,5.0957,4.6871,5.5043,-6.121,-6.6252,-5.6168
18.36,5.1163,4.6108,5.6219,-6.1105,-6.4983,-5.7228
18.4,5.1113,4.552,5.6707,-6.1097,-6.4176,-5.8018
18.44,5.0769,4.4655,5.6882,-6.0077,-6.1584,-5.857
18.48,5.024,4.429,5.619,-5.8976,-5.9908,-5.8044
18.52,4.9433,4.379,5.5075,-5.817,-5.8561,-5.7779
18.56,4.9255,4.5078,5.3431,-5.7114,-5.8355,-5.5872
18.6,4.8675,4.5365,5.1986,-5.671,-5.9144,-5.4277
18.64,4.8916,4.542,5.2412,-5.6676,-5.9986,-5.3366
18.68,4.9136,4.5336,5.2936,-5.6689,-6.0576,-5.2802
18.72,4.9358,4.5112,5.3603,-5.6794,-6.0281,-5.3307
18.76,4.9601,4.5008,5.4194,-5.6619,-5.9478,-5.3759
18.8,4.9299,4.4391,5.4208,-5.6609,-5.8726,-5.4492
18.84,4.8939,4.391,5.3967,-5.6293,-5.8169,-5.4416
18.88,4.8567,4.3906,5.3227,-5.5642,-5.7164,-5.412
18.92,4.8081,4.3724,5.2438,-5.5031,-5.6676,-5.3386
18.96,4.7936,4.3971,5.1902,-5.4604,-5.66,-5.2608
19,4.7795,4.4653,5.0938,-5.4183,-5.6689,-5.1678
19.04,4.7744,4.5056,5.0431,-5.3854,-5.697,-5.0738
19.08,4.7699,4.508,5.0318,-5.385,-5.7493,-5.0206
19.12,4.8036,4.5167,5.0905,-5.3959,-5.6815,-5.1104
19.16,4.8459,4.4952,5.1966,-5.3865,-5.6896,-5.0833
19.2,4.818,4.4388,5.1971,-5.3842,-5.6608,-5.1077
19.24,4.8336,4.4383,5.2288,-5.3595,-5.6469,-5.0722
19.28,4.8009,4.4178,5.184,-5.3325,-5.6355,-5.0295
19.32,4.7595,4.4106,5.1084,-5.2892,-5.641,-4.9374
19.36,4.7173,4.4114,5.0231,-5.2491,-5.6541,-4.844
19.4,4.6769,4.4033,4.9505,-5.242,-5.6535,-4.8306
19.44,4.6776,4.442,4.9131,-5.211,-5.6152,-4.8068
19.48,4.6882,4.4452,4.9312,-5.2171,-5.5881,-4.8461
19.52,4.6876,4.4074,4.9677,-5.2424,-5.5984,-4.8865
19.56,4.7373,4.4447,5.0298,-5.2465,-5.558,-4.935
19.6,4.7371,4.4209,5.0534,-5.2397,-5.5585,-4.9209
19.64,4.7339,4.412,5.0559,-5.2326,-5.5612,-4.904
19.68,4.7239,4.4156,5.0321,-5.2074,-5.5627,-4.8521
19.72,4.7017,4.3925,5.011,-5.2004,-5.5351,-4.8658
19.76,4.7158,4.4064,5.0252,-5.1445,-5.5405,-4.7486
19.8,4.669,4.3757,4.9622,-5.1503,-5.5632,-4.7375
19.84,4.6676,4.3818,4.9534,-5.1346,-5.5725,-4.6966
19.88,4.6688,4.4059,4.9316,-5.131,-5.5751,-4.6868
19.92,4.6429,4.3666,4.9192,-5.1293,-5.5824,-4.6763
19.96,4.6292,4.3271,4.9313,-5.1395,-5.6057,-4.6732
20,4.6227,4.3073,4.9381,-5.127,-5.5838,-4.6702
20.04,4.6365,4.3139,4.9591,-5.1243,-5.57,-4.6787
20.08,4.6179,4.2308,5.0049,-5.2145,-5.6812,-4.7477
20.12,4.5253,4.15,4.9006,-5.1936,-5.6417,-4.7455
20.16,4.387,3.9901,4.7839,-5.1153,-5.5297,-4.7008
20.2,4.0763,3.6647,4.4879,-5.0668,-5.5119,-4.6217
20.24,3.839,3.5204,4.1576,-5.0116,-5.4439,-4.5793
20.28,3.589,3.2374,3.9406,-4.9881,-5.4315,-4.5447
20.32,3.3876,3.0685,3.7067,-4.9713,-5.4325,-4.51
20.36,3.2746,2.9984,3.5508,-4.9879,-5.4735,-4.5024
20.4,3.2044,2.9199,3.4888,-5.0463,-5.5496,-4.5429
20.44,3.1997,2.9432,3.4562,-5.0686,-5.567,-4.5703
20.48,3.2122,2.9727,3.4517,-5.0777,-5.5586,-4.5967
20.52,3.1929,2.8984,3.4874,-5.1291,-5.6366,-4.6216
20.56,3.1998,2.9149,3.4847,-5.1101,-5.5807,-4.6395
20.6,3.128,2.824,3.4319,-5.0779,-5.539,-4.6168
20.64,3.0308,2.7096,3.3519,-5.0499,-5.5029,-4.5969
20.68,2.908,2.6227,3.1933,-5.0233,-5.4846,-4.562
20.72,2.7801,2.5037,3.0565,-5.0065,-5.4457,-4.5673
20.76,2.702,2.4063,2.9978,-4.9641,-5.4291,-4.4992
20.8,2.6183,2.3738,2.8628,-4.9902,-5.4271,-4.5533
20.84,2.5773,2.3206,2.8341,-4.9893,-5.421,-4.5575
20.88,2.5537,2.2834,2.824,-5.0028,-5.4192,-4.5864
20.92,2.5467,2.2659,2.8274,-5.0261,-5.4313,-4.6209
}\dummydata
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel = {$x$ [$\sim$]},
    ylabel = {$y$ [$\sim$]},
    zlabel = {$z$ [$\sim$]},
    legend cell align={left},
    ]
    {
        \addplot3 [mark = none, color = blue] table [x =xm, y =ym, z=tm]
        {\dummydata};
        \addplot3 [mark = none, color = green] table [x =xmd, y =ymd, z=tm]
        {\dummydata};
        \addplot3 [mark = none, color = red] table [x =xpd, y =ypd, z=tm]
        {\dummydata};
        \legend{the center, radius 1, radius 2}
    }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which will give me:

[image]

Here considering the solid-blue as my center, and solid-green and -red as outer radii for the tube, I wish to achieve the tube-like region.

Comment: What you could do is plot something like the top and bottom lines using \addplot3 then draw the circles (ellipses?) using regular tikz commands.  The tricky bit is computing the x and y radii to scale.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tried your comment even before posting here but to much of my expectations it was unsuccessful indeed. Because, exactly at the radius part, I could no longer move forward (I got literally lost, up till now). In addition, I could not successfully recreate the shaded region with gradients.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228711/drawing-an-ellipse-inside-a-pgfplots-semilog-axis for example.  And you might need pgfplotstable to access the data.

Comment: I am not sure but believe that it would be a bit easier to draw this with `tikz-3dplot`. My main problem is, though, that I do not see how one would get the desired output from 3 parallel lines. Wouldn't one get a straight tube here?

Comment: @John Kormylo thanks for the suggestion I'll look into it.

Comment: @marmot yes of course we will get a straight tube here :) this is just an example, I have a much bigger data-set to interpret fancy stuffs ;) if u could show me how, it would be great. (I always try to simplify the data-set to not make it complicated;))

Comment: must be extremely hard and frustrating to do with `pgfplots` or `tikz`. Perhaps `asymptote` would be a better option http://www.piprime.fr/files/asymptote/tube/ , see example #8. or https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c521529h1515055_rainbow_spring_thing

Comment: @alfC I will try that :) But I am looking for a `TeX` based solution. `Asymptote` is  something really new for me. Could you tell me whether I can integrate it with `TeX` as I can do with `TikZ`?

Comment: @Raaja, Asymptote is considered a TeX friend, it uses TeX internally and it integrates well with LaTeX. It is basically a programming language (just as TeX) for creating 2D and 3D scenes. You will see many Asymptote Q&A in this site. Also, there is an `asy` package to integrate Asymptote code in a LaTeX document.

Comment: @alfC In that case, I will dive into that this weekend :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an answer but to illustrate why I do not know what to do with your data. Yes, it is simple, but unfortunately it is not really suited to test some nontrivial things. So the following may or may not work for some real data (most likely it won't but I do not have the patience to create some data).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445369/121799
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\pgfplotstableread{
T1 T3 v11   v12 v13
0   0 0.66582 0.76 0.63
1   .000125 0.66582 0.76    0.63
2   .00025 0.66582  0.76    0.63
3   .000375 0.66582 0.76    0.63
4   .0005 0.66582   0.76    0.63
5   .000625 0.66582 0.76    0.63
6   .00075 0.66582  0.76    0.63
7   .000875 0.66582 0.76    0.63
8   .001 0.66582    0.76    0.63
9   .001125 0.66582 0.76    0.63
}\dummydata
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\dummydata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownum}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\foreach \X in {1,...,\rownum}
{\ReadOutElement{\dummydata}{\X}{T1}{\tmpx}
\ReadOutElement{\dummydata}{\X}{T3}{\tmpy}
\ReadOutElement{\dummydata}{\X}{v11}{\tmpz}
\ReadOutElement{\dummydata}{\X}{v12}{\tmpRone}
\ReadOutElement{\dummydata}{\X}{v13}{\tmpRtwo} % will be ignored
\typeout{\tmpx,\tmpy,\tmpz,\tmpRone}
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=\tmpx,transform shape]
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=\tmpRone] (c-\X) at (\tmpy,\tmpz){};
\end{scope}
}
\draw plot[samples at={1,...,\rownum},variable=\x,smooth] (c-\x.80);
\draw plot[samples at={1,...,\rownum},variable=\x,smooth] (c-\x.-100);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a status report on the example with more complex data. The result is far from perfect. Even though one can achieve some features by cheating or some analytic computation or approximation, it always comes back to the fact that Ti*k*Z does not have a 3d engine.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445369/121799
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{
tm,xm,xmd,xpd,ym,ymd,ypd
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0.04,0,0,0,0,0,0
0.08,0,0,0,0,0,0
0.12,0.34111,-2.4039,3.0861,-0.51786,-3.8303,2.7946
0.16,0.31078,-2.4179,3.0395,-0.54815,-3.9037,2.8074
0.2,0.32704,-2.4167,3.0707,-0.57982,-3.9058,2.7461
0.24,0.26665,-2.4367,2.97,-0.70117,-3.9647,2.5624
0.28,0.21992,-2.283,2.7228,-0.86952,-3.9877,2.2486
0.32,0.16058,-2.1158,2.437,-0.96921,-3.8313,1.8929
0.36,0.015983,-1.9724,2.0043,-1.0393,-3.6891,1.6105
0.4,-0.052178,-1.767,1.6626,-1.1558,-3.5265,1.2149
0.44,-0.12252,-1.5715,1.3265,-1.1154,-3.2262,0.99543
0.48,-0.15534,-1.3355,1.0248,-1.09,-2.9273,0.74723
0.52,-0.15089,-1.1588,0.85702,-1.0373,-2.7046,0.63006
0.56,-0.13807,-1.0788,0.80265,-0.96654,-2.4969,0.56384
0.6,-0.088093,-0.97758,0.80139,-0.90801,-2.3491,0.5331
0.64,-0.069781,-0.94086,0.80129,-0.89427,-2.3047,0.5162
0.68,-0.020531,-0.94687,0.90581,-0.818,-2.2231,0.58707
0.72,-0.027254,-0.96119,0.90668,-0.83075,-2.173,0.51149
0.76,-0.031288,-0.94815,0.88558,-0.82597,-2.2118,0.55987
0.8,-0.031409,-0.91782,0.855,-0.80136,-2.1164,0.51368
0.84,-0.063101,-0.84579,0.71959,-0.82437,-2.0932,0.44447
0.88,-0.09426,-0.80363,0.61511,-0.81774,-2.0294,0.39393
0.92,-0.12187,-0.71312,0.46938,-0.82512,-1.9138,0.26358
0.96,-0.13254,-0.63217,0.36709,-0.83908,-1.8382,0.16004
1,-0.12502,-0.64794,0.3979,-0.8046,-1.709,0.099775
1.04,-0.11963,-0.55243,0.31316,-0.8349,-1.6507,-0.019066
1.08,-0.1045,-0.58747,0.37847,-0.83788,-1.6403,-0.035508
1.12,-0.062444,-0.56731,0.44242,-0.78585,-1.4928,-0.078868
1.16,-0.079204,-0.6093,0.4509,-0.8005,-1.5141,-0.086878
1.2,-0.084476,-0.60549,0.43653,-0.80424,-1.5102,-0.098265
1.24,-0.082068,-0.5689,0.40476,-0.79587,-1.4862,-0.10553
1.28,-0.099081,-0.57148,0.37332,-0.78828,-1.4717,-0.1049
1.32,-0.13329,-0.60353,0.33696,-0.81407,-1.4543,-0.17382
1.36,-0.096508,-0.47577,0.28276,-0.78266,-1.4171,-0.14827
1.4,-0.14497,-0.56515,0.27521,-0.81147,-1.3793,-0.24363
1.44,-0.12127,-0.51149,0.26894,-0.78772,-1.3515,-0.22388
1.48,-0.1217,-0.51802,0.27463,-0.78803,-1.3051,-0.271
1.52,-0.12173,-0.51559,0.27214,-0.79021,-1.2825,-0.29787
1.56,-0.10114,-0.51495,0.31267,-0.77804,-1.2414,-0.31463
1.6,-0.1014,-0.50952,0.30672,-0.76874,-1.1943,-0.34319
1.64,-0.11196,-0.48854,0.26461,-0.7622,-1.1585,-0.36586
1.68,-0.053825,-0.4586,0.35095,-0.71589,-1.108,-0.32376
1.72,-0.078095,-0.43485,0.27866,-0.73016,-1.0662,-0.39413
1.76,-0.080373,-0.47621,0.31547,-0.72842,-1.1203,-0.33655
1.8,-0.039621,-0.40915,0.3299,-0.68146,-1.0132,-0.34977
1.84,-0.062119,-0.43261,0.30837,-0.69357,-1.0315,-0.35569
1.88,-0.057911,-0.41945,0.30363,-0.67735,-1.0079,-0.34684
1.92,-0.053722,-0.40234,0.29489,-0.67227,-0.95972,-0.38482
1.96,-0.065276,-0.39114,0.26058,-0.68735,-0.94931,-0.42539
2,-0.037894,-0.39006,0.31428,-0.66806,-0.90303,-0.43309
2.04,-0.036814,-0.31968,0.24605,-0.66693,-0.89665,-0.4372
2.08,-0.038017,-0.35327,0.27724,-0.67016,-0.9178,-0.42253
2.12,-0.0097459,-0.29652,0.27703,-0.64795,-0.86252,-0.43338
2.16,-0.017039,-0.3108,0.27673,-0.64223,-0.86004,-0.42443
2.2,-0.010354,-0.3032,0.28249,-0.63579,-0.8435,-0.42808
2.24,-0.0075316,-0.2807,0.26564,-0.61478,-0.78884,-0.44073
2.28,-0.011665,-0.31125,0.28792,-0.60756,-0.75897,-0.45614
2.32,-0.031825,-0.32928,0.26563,-0.6092,-0.71376,-0.50465
2.36,0.00065694,-0.29614,0.29746,-0.5606,-0.70139,-0.41982
2.4,0.0043591,-0.30116,0.30988,-0.55409,-0.65516,-0.45303
2.44,0.00056132,-0.32006,0.32119,-0.54239,-0.64429,-0.44049
2.48,0.0080039,-0.31491,0.33092,-0.54615,-0.64203,-0.45027
2.52,0.017543,-0.29376,0.32884,-0.54204,-0.62597,-0.45812
2.56,0.043735,-0.25843,0.3459,-0.52438,-0.58751,-0.46125
2.6,0.053718,-0.2384,0.34583,-0.49305,-0.52909,-0.45702
2.64,0.046364,-0.20966,0.30239,-0.47018,-0.53222,-0.40814
2.68,0.079327,-0.20243,0.36109,-0.37582,-0.40642,-0.34523
2.72,0.072251,-0.20886,0.35336,-0.34565,-0.38803,-0.30328
2.76,0.051764,-0.2224,0.32593,-0.323,-0.37129,-0.27472
2.8,0.049093,-0.22782,0.32601,-0.25679,-0.30908,-0.2045
2.84,0.038224,-0.23386,0.31031,-0.23561,-0.29658,-0.17464
2.88,0.02659,-0.27056,0.32374,-0.196,-0.29468,-0.097316
2.92,0.003124,-0.31375,0.32,-0.17749,-0.27682,-0.078165
2.96,-0.0018435,-0.29729,0.2936,-0.16058,-0.27943,-0.041725
3,-0.006709,-0.39879,0.38537,-0.15632,-0.21252,-0.10013
3.04,-0.033639,-0.35582,0.28854,-0.15892,-0.24118,-0.076667
3.08,-0.032483,-0.38838,0.32341,-0.14021,-0.18432,-0.096106
3.12,-0.029824,-0.36757,0.30792,-0.11038,-0.15382,-0.066938
3.16,-0.037045,-0.38856,0.31447,-0.095147,-0.16009,-0.030209
3.2,-0.05167,-0.40226,0.29892,-0.06759,-0.11908,-0.016101
3.24,-0.049338,-0.39622,0.29754,-0.051711,-0.123,0.019576
3.28,-0.042641,-0.37827,0.29299,-0.028917,-0.13901,0.081174
3.32,-0.087298,-0.44836,0.27376,-0.034339,-0.11291,0.044231
3.36,-0.063621,-0.40711,0.27987,-0.0035416,-0.16211,0.15503
3.4,-0.056421,-0.4119,0.29906,0.019537,-0.087551,0.12663
3.44,-0.075507,-0.46623,0.31522,-0.013768,-0.15164,0.1241
3.48,-0.063827,-0.44935,0.3217,0.0064244,-0.11088,0.12373
3.52,-0.063597,-0.45513,0.32794,0.011473,-0.076058,0.099004
3.56,-0.050908,-0.45053,0.34871,0.03448,-0.045832,0.11479
3.6,-0.033273,-0.46869,0.40214,0.050067,-0.015407,0.11554
3.64,-0.066905,-0.44499,0.31118,0.017897,-0.067961,0.10375
3.68,-0.046271,-0.48794,0.39539,0.033531,-0.069233,0.1363
3.72,-0.05138,-0.45257,0.34981,0.05112,-0.029063,0.1313
3.76,-0.070642,-0.49432,0.35304,0.014393,-0.11913,0.14792
3.8,-0.070007,-0.47799,0.33798,0.030181,-0.093617,0.15398
3.84,-0.078997,-0.47921,0.32122,0.0099555,-0.13733,0.15724
3.88,-0.064307,-0.46206,0.33344,0.011714,-0.11396,0.13738
3.92,-0.068079,-0.46893,0.33277,0.018777,-0.09173,0.12928
3.96,-0.053161,-0.42124,0.31492,0.01825,-0.099128,0.13563
4,-0.022433,-0.49323,0.44836,0.037708,-0.02134,0.096756
4.04,-0.033149,-0.45834,0.39204,0.04793,-0.032419,0.12828
4.08,-0.041493,-0.47415,0.39117,0.040858,-0.021069,0.10278
4.12,-0.057713,-0.46698,0.35155,0.039439,-0.042223,0.1211
4.16,-0.054769,-0.44338,0.33385,0.048358,-0.047295,0.14401
4.2,-0.063519,-0.46221,0.33517,0.038351,-0.041262,0.11796
4.24,-0.063892,-0.44782,0.32004,0.036186,-0.068824,0.1412
4.28,-0.056123,-0.40631,0.29407,0.0476,-0.064233,0.15943
4.32,-0.094136,-0.45608,0.2678,0.015395,-0.083746,0.11454
4.36,-0.073154,-0.4461,0.29979,0.030337,-0.14479,0.20547
4.4,-0.050985,-0.42611,0.32414,0.06799,-0.017188,0.15317
4.44,-0.069921,-0.47383,0.33399,0.056972,-0.075461,0.1894
4.48,-0.05228,-0.46064,0.35608,0.083086,-0.0056697,0.17184
4.52,-0.05134,-0.45118,0.3485,0.096423,0.0019748,0.19087
4.56,-0.052724,-0.46209,0.35664,0.086379,-0.011513,0.18427
4.6,-0.043504,-0.50302,0.41601,0.080933,-0.015713,0.17758
4.64,-0.084016,-0.46078,0.29275,0.036149,-0.07109,0.14339
4.68,-0.05337,-0.4727,0.36596,0.051233,-0.075305,0.17777
4.72,-0.047571,-0.43556,0.34042,0.058992,-0.021999,0.13998
4.76,-0.076011,-0.486,0.33398,0.020806,-0.10033,0.14194
4.8,-0.06046,-0.46313,0.34221,0.052942,-0.049416,0.1553
4.84,-0.063963,-0.48172,0.3538,0.046092,-0.050885,0.14307
4.88,-0.05335,-0.48394,0.37724,0.066777,-0.038134,0.17169
4.92,-0.056813,-0.49169,0.37807,0.079715,-0.030218,0.18965
4.96,-0.053435,-0.43036,0.32349,0.089452,-0.027211,0.20611
5,-0.053848,-0.52124,0.41355,0.10071,-0.0093193,0.21073
5.04,-0.083567,-0.50769,0.34056,0.073753,-0.090077,0.23758
5.08,-0.07258,-0.45966,0.3145,0.08868,-0.05089,0.22825
5.12,0.00084803,-0.39465,0.39635,0.048857,-0.12497,0.22269
5.16,0.13554,-0.27892,0.55001,0.041207,-0.12962,0.21203
5.2,0.40825,-0.069637,0.88613,0.050071,-0.1298,0.22994
5.24,0.67117,0.21572,1.1266,0.048443,-0.10058,0.19747
5.28,1.0633,0.45878,1.6678,0.090288,-0.08581,0.26638
5.32,1.4693,0.80123,2.1374,0.089672,-0.070362,0.24971
5.36,1.7759,1.0413,2.5104,0.11808,-0.08123,0.31739
5.4,2.2478,1.4725,3.0231,0.18277,0.021067,0.34448
5.44,2.6068,1.7448,3.4688,0.19036,0.0073643,0.37336
5.48,2.909,2.0545,3.7635,0.19718,0.0052129,0.38915
5.52,3.2663,2.3967,4.136,0.20015,0.031327,0.36896
5.56,3.5597,2.6781,4.4413,0.20717,0.042911,0.37144
6.76,6.4335,6.1771,6.6899,0.24583,0.11987,0.37179
6.8,6.4503,6.2052,6.6953,0.24771,0.12392,0.3715
6.84,6.4881,6.2321,6.7441,0.25109,0.13723,0.36495
6.88,6.5094,6.2602,6.7585,0.24703,0.13902,0.35503
6.92,6.5216,6.2973,6.7459,0.25129,0.16407,0.33851
6.96,6.5899,6.3593,6.8205,0.25022,0.14516,0.35527
7,6.6188,6.4196,6.818,0.24323,0.19472,0.29175
7.04,6.6412,6.3826,6.8998,0.23618,0.14959,0.32277
7.08,6.6917,6.412,6.9713,0.24519,0.18214,0.30823
7.12,6.7147,6.3912,7.0383,0.2398,0.18131,0.2983
7.16,6.7315,6.3803,7.0827,0.24463,0.15948,0.32977
7.2,6.7522,6.381,7.1235,0.26291,0.16465,0.36116
7.24,6.7502,6.3647,7.1358,0.25668,0.11773,0.39564
7.28,6.7824,6.4031,7.1617,0.28356,0.14323,0.42389
7.32,6.7894,6.4244,7.1545,0.27849,0.12083,0.43615
7.36,6.8157,6.4514,7.18,0.27862,0.10427,0.45297
7.4,6.8482,6.5263,7.1701,0.30119,0.14656,0.45583
7.44,6.8305,6.4684,7.1927,0.29605,0.14886,0.44324
7.48,6.8442,6.4659,7.2226,0.30386,0.15869,0.44903
7.52,6.8506,6.4286,7.2727,0.30484,0.15302,0.45666
7.56,6.8496,6.4125,7.2867,0.29756,0.1237,0.47142
7.6,6.8548,6.4366,7.273,0.25163,0.14919,0.35408
7.64,6.8741,6.4435,7.3046,0.1238,-0.039884,0.28748
7.68,6.8937,6.5022,7.2853,-0.017529,-0.14808,0.11302
7.72,6.9162,6.5359,7.2964,-0.32985,-0.48445,-0.17526
7.76,6.9465,6.5946,7.2984,-0.59723,-0.69643,-0.49803
7.8,6.9923,6.6637,7.3208,-0.97282,-1.171,-0.77466
7.84,7.0541,6.7295,7.3786,-1.4468,-1.6747,-1.219
7.88,7.0898,6.7545,7.425,-1.7771,-2.0199,-1.5343
7.92,7.1271,6.7552,7.4989,-2.2983,-2.5595,-2.037
7.96,7.1138,6.6874,7.5402,-2.7553,-3.1106,-2.4001
8,7.0718,6.6872,7.4564,-3.0869,-3.4405,-2.7333
8.04,7.0063,6.5691,7.4436,-3.5022,-3.8674,-3.137
8.08,6.9727,6.5442,7.4012,-3.7816,-4.1216,-3.4416
8.12,6.9554,6.5244,7.3865,-4.1073,-4.5071,-3.7075
8.16,6.9803,6.5929,7.3678,-4.4256,-4.8657,-3.9854
8.2,7.0041,6.6295,7.3787,-4.6424,-5.0375,-4.2473
8.24,7.0188,6.656,7.3815,-4.8274,-5.2412,-4.4135
8.28,7.0472,6.6968,7.3976,-4.9368,-5.2982,-4.5754
8.32,7.0483,6.6807,7.4159,-5.0095,-5.2984,-4.7206
8.36,7.0263,6.6358,7.4167,-5.0906,-5.3505,-4.8308
8.4,7.0195,6.6356,7.4033,-5.1708,-5.4009,-4.9407
8.44,7.0289,6.6191,7.4388,-5.2772,-5.501,-5.0533
8.48,7.063,6.661,7.465,-5.4327,-5.6855,-5.1798
8.52,7.0909,6.6867,7.4952,-5.5987,-5.8348,-5.3625
8.56,7.1166,6.6788,7.5543,-5.8046,-6.1261,-5.4831
8.6,7.121,6.6979,7.5442,-5.996,-6.3047,-5.6872
8.64,7.0953,6.5918,7.5989,-6.1159,-6.4159,-5.816
8.68,7.0522,6.5205,7.5838,-6.2303,-6.5434,-5.9173
8.72,6.9995,6.437,7.5621,-6.2855,-6.5682,-6.0027
8.76,6.9611,6.3757,7.5465,-6.3131,-6.5813,-6.0448
8.8,6.8916,6.2743,7.509,-6.3218,-6.5595,-6.084
8.84,6.8692,6.2553,7.4831,-6.3418,-6.5496,-6.1341
8.88,6.8868,6.2735,7.5001,-6.3578,-6.5522,-6.1634
8.92,6.9582,6.3996,7.5168,-6.4474,-6.674,-6.2209
8.96,7.0188,6.4351,7.6026,-6.5521,-6.8008,-6.3035
9,7.1062,6.5974,7.615,-6.6711,-6.9728,-6.3694
9.04,7.1562,6.6706,7.6418,-6.8161,-7.0907,-6.5415
9.08,7.1891,6.7355,7.6427,-6.8684,-7.0917,-6.645
9.12,7.1411,6.6381,7.6441,-6.88,-7.116,-6.644
9.16,7.052,6.4883,7.6156,-6.8336,-7.0969,-6.5704
9.2,6.9774,6.3824,7.5724,-6.7699,-7.0076,-6.5321
9.24,6.9156,6.3152,7.5159,-6.7387,-6.9156,-6.5618
9.28,6.9542,6.4245,7.4839,-6.7725,-7.0108,-6.5343
9.32,7.0016,6.4507,7.5526,-6.834,-7.1523,-6.5156
9.36,7.169,6.6666,7.6715,-6.9756,-7.3914,-6.5597
9.4,7.2619,6.7704,7.7534,-7.0933,-7.5018,-6.6848
9.44,7.3342,6.9428,7.7256,-7.2009,-7.5759,-6.826
9.48,7.3422,6.9404,7.744,-7.2382,-7.559,-6.9175
9.52,7.3034,6.8612,7.7456,-7.2004,-7.4885,-6.9124
9.56,7.1462,6.5482,7.7443,-7.1165,-7.3986,-6.8344
9.6,7.0407,6.5134,7.5681,-7.0325,-7.2877,-6.7773
9.64,6.9497,6.3851,7.5143,-6.971,-7.1549,-6.7871
9.68,6.9977,6.4771,7.5182,-7.0397,-7.4102,-6.6691
9.72,7.0861,6.5399,7.6323,-7.1605,-7.6829,-6.638
9.76,7.267,6.8108,7.7231,-7.3677,-8.0191,-6.7163
9.8,7.4187,7.0903,7.7471,-7.5638,-8.2129,-6.9146
9.84,7.5155,7.222,7.8089,-7.6459,-8.262,-7.0297
9.88,7.4995,7.1265,7.8725,-7.6468,-8.2183,-7.0753
9.92,7.3399,6.8646,7.8151,-7.555,-8.0892,-7.0208
9.96,7.2109,6.6922,7.7296,-7.4577,-7.9734,-6.942
10,7.0758,6.592,7.5595,-7.3723,-7.7758,-6.9688
10.04,7.0355,6.6073,7.4638,-7.3607,-7.7956,-6.9257
10.08,7.0587,6.586,7.5315,-7.4092,-7.9834,-6.835
10.12,7.2429,6.7083,7.7774,-7.6065,-8.3659,-6.847
10.16,7.4034,6.9113,7.8955,-7.7812,-8.5842,-6.9781
10.2,7.5615,7.3003,7.8227,-7.9624,-8.7897,-7.1351
10.24,7.616,7.3577,7.8744,-8.0548,-8.8964,-7.2132
10.28,7.5448,7.1839,7.9057,-8.0201,-8.8291,-7.2111
10.32,7.387,6.8901,7.8838,-7.8865,-8.6371,-7.1359
10.36,7.2264,6.7905,7.6623,-7.7327,-8.4122,-7.0531
10.4,7.1643,6.7736,7.555,-7.6768,-8.3274,-7.0262
10.44,7.1903,6.7654,7.6152,-7.6918,-8.4264,-6.9571
10.48,7.3427,6.7498,7.9355,-7.8483,-8.7806,-6.916
10.52,7.4903,6.8832,8.0974,-8.0292,-9.0224,-7.0361
10.56,7.7234,7.2576,8.1892,-8.2671,-9.2216,-7.3127
10.6,7.84,7.4842,8.1958,-8.4146,-9.2455,-7.5838
10.64,7.8325,7.4521,8.2129,-8.4221,-9.216,-7.6283
10.68,7.686,7.2564,8.1155,-8.2886,-9.0407,-7.5364
10.72,7.5263,7.0998,7.9529,-8.0951,-8.8397,-7.3506
10.76,7.3631,6.9396,7.7865,-7.8994,-8.5654,-7.2334
10.8,7.219,6.7484,7.6896,-7.7601,-8.4708,-7.0494
10.84,7.2715,6.6986,7.8444,-7.8114,-8.6497,-6.9731
10.88,7.4858,6.7656,8.206,-8.0509,-9.0253,-7.0764
10.92,7.736,6.9685,8.5036,-8.3467,-9.2164,-7.4771
10.96,7.9589,7.3295,8.5883,-8.6155,-9.3578,-7.8732
11,8.0919,7.4751,8.7088,-8.7833,-9.4115,-8.155
11.04,8.0053,7.3923,8.6183,-8.7394,-9.3799,-8.0988
11.08,7.8173,7.176,8.4586,-8.5279,-9.1881,-7.8676
11.12,7.5877,6.9553,8.2201,-8.2838,-8.9086,-7.6591
11.16,7.4758,6.9209,8.0307,-8.136,-8.7648,-7.5073
11.2,7.4464,6.8011,8.0917,-8.077,-8.6354,-7.5186
11.24,7.6276,6.7951,8.46,-8.2437,-8.9473,-7.5401
11.28,7.8597,6.9583,8.7611,-8.4336,-9.1375,-7.7297
11.32,8.1823,7.2603,9.1043,-8.7751,-9.3313,-8.2188
11.36,8.3611,7.4759,9.2462,-8.926,-9.2665,-8.5856
11.4,8.3824,7.5894,9.1754,-8.9688,-9.3756,-8.562
11.44,8.1936,7.5055,8.8817,-8.786,-9.288,-8.2839
11.48,7.9719,7.3563,8.5875,-8.5793,-9.166,-7.9926
11.52,7.7549,7.1856,8.3243,-8.3558,-8.8653,-7.8462
11.56,7.6155,7.0069,8.2241,-8.1745,-8.6248,-7.7242
11.6,7.6205,6.9457,8.2954,-8.2028,-8.6084,-7.7971
11.64,7.8577,6.9545,8.7609,-8.3849,-9.0302,-7.7397
11.68,8.1678,7.0749,9.2608,-8.7006,-9.4053,-7.9959
11.72,8.3917,7.3443,9.439,-8.982,-9.5189,-8.4452
11.76,8.5678,7.6396,9.4961,-9.1095,-9.4504,-8.7686
11.8,8.4624,7.626,9.2989,-8.9957,-9.4007,-8.5907
11.84,8.3294,7.5415,9.1173,-8.8516,-9.38,-8.3232
11.88,8.091,7.3196,8.8624,-8.5691,-9.1187,-8.0194
11.92,7.9079,7.2791,8.5366,-8.3941,-8.96,-7.8282
11.96,7.8445,7.0898,8.5992,-8.3102,-8.8217,-7.7987
12,7.9816,7.0019,8.9613,-8.4754,-9.2098,-7.7411
12.04,8.1679,6.987,9.3489,-8.6768,-9.5306,-7.823
12.08,8.3604,7.132,9.5888,-8.9552,-9.8836,-8.0269
12.12,8.4423,7.3428,9.5419,-9.0546,-9.6396,-8.4696
12.16,8.5183,7.646,9.3906,-9.1469,-9.5624,-8.7314
12.2,8.4105,7.7887,9.0322,-9.058,-9.4954,-8.6206
12.24,8.2313,7.7486,8.7139,-8.8548,-9.3988,-8.3108
12.28,8.0632,7.6282,8.4981,-8.6484,-9.2335,-8.0632
12.32,7.8982,7.3276,8.4689,-8.4582,-9.1113,-7.8051
12.36,7.9176,7.1409,8.6943,-8.4585,-9.1423,-7.7747
12.4,8.0588,6.9721,9.1455,-8.573,-9.4289,-7.7171
12.44,8.3161,7.0408,9.5914,-8.801,-9.6024,-7.9996
12.48,8.5953,7.2536,9.9369,-8.9989,-9.6354,-8.3624
12.52,8.7016,7.5325,9.8708,-9.1714,-9.5738,-8.769
12.56,8.6841,7.6921,9.6761,-9.1068,-9.3105,-8.903
12.6,8.6335,7.8298,9.4371,-9.0789,-9.3712,-8.7866
12.64,8.4065,7.6868,9.1262,-8.8581,-9.2483,-8.4678
12.68,8.2158,7.6246,8.8071,-8.653,-9.1138,-8.1921
12.72,8.08,7.3868,8.7732,-8.5101,-8.9045,-8.1156
12.76,8.0294,7.1304,8.9284,-8.4587,-8.8631,-8.0542
12.8,8.1312,7.0364,9.226,-8.5674,-9.0251,-8.1098
12.84,8.316,7.0534,9.5785,-8.7166,-9.3139,-8.1194
12.88,8.4955,7.1897,9.8012,-8.8445,-9.3924,-8.2967
12.92,8.5834,7.4362,9.7307,-8.9613,-9.3424,-8.5802
12.96,8.6169,7.7417,9.492,-8.9791,-9.1952,-8.763
13,8.4831,7.8227,9.1435,-8.8585,-9.1409,-8.5761
13.04,8.331,7.7631,8.899,-8.6955,-9.0472,-8.3439
13.08,8.0345,7.6093,8.4597,-8.3997,-8.8241,-7.9752
13.12,7.8765,7.4636,8.2895,-8.22,-8.6407,-7.7993
13.16,7.7856,7.1466,8.4246,-8.1193,-8.3936,-7.8449
13.2,7.8842,6.9836,8.7847,-8.243,-8.5545,-7.9315
13.24,8.1421,6.9618,9.3223,-8.4929,-8.8825,-8.1033
13.28,8.4318,7.2089,9.6547,-8.7445,-9.2216,-8.2674
13.32,8.5441,7.3571,9.731,-8.8794,-9.2427,-8.5162
13.36,8.6136,7.7292,9.4981,-8.9508,-9.1558,-8.7458
13.4,8.4702,7.8355,9.1048,-8.8271,-9.1617,-8.4925
13.44,8.2577,7.7884,8.727,-8.6168,-9.0765,-8.157
13.48,8.0814,7.5981,8.5647,-8.4101,-8.8263,-7.9939
13.52,7.8933,7.3123,8.4744,-8.2215,-8.47,-7.973
15.36,7.2138,6.5296,7.898,-8.5991,-8.6488,-8.5493
15.4,7.1106,6.5327,7.6886,-8.6298,-8.9497,-8.3098
15.44,6.9851,6.4236,7.5467,-8.6449,-8.9982,-8.2915
15.48,6.8448,6.257,7.4326,-8.5407,-8.7818,-8.2996
15.52,6.7419,6.1343,7.3496,-8.5791,-8.7467,-8.4115
15.56,6.6545,5.865,7.444,-8.4884,-8.7791,-8.1977
15.6,6.548,5.5956,7.5005,-8.4138,-8.9103,-7.9174
15.64,6.4446,5.49,7.3993,-8.3434,-8.8305,-7.8563
15.68,6.3337,5.4411,7.2262,-8.3013,-8.7003,-7.9022
15.72,6.2438,5.5468,6.9408,-8.3073,-8.474,-8.1407
15.76,6.1374,5.6962,6.5787,-8.2497,-8.3804,-8.1191
15.8,6.0879,5.7563,6.4196,-8.2948,-8.5981,-7.9916
15.84,6.0485,5.7321,6.3649,-8.3143,-8.737,-7.8917
15.88,5.9958,5.6467,6.345,-8.2947,-8.6478,-7.9417
15.92,5.9272,5.4427,6.4118,-8.266,-8.4633,-8.0688
15.96,5.8753,5.2035,6.547,-8.2425,-8.5263,-7.9588
16,5.7818,4.9646,6.599,-8.1543,-8.6346,-7.674
16.04,5.6813,4.7773,6.5853,-8.0588,-8.5878,-7.5298
16.08,5.6191,4.8193,6.4189,-8.0331,-8.4484,-7.6179
16.12,5.6281,5.002,6.2541,-8.1211,-8.3452,-7.8969
16.16,5.7124,5.3256,6.0992,-8.2116,-8.3616,-8.0616
16.2,5.6929,5.4639,5.922,-8.2367,-8.6291,-7.8444
16.24,5.7247,5.3984,6.0509,-8.2925,-8.8279,-7.757
16.28,5.694,5.3375,6.0504,-8.2859,-8.7903,-7.7814
16.32,5.6315,5.213,6.0499,-8.2435,-8.67,-7.817
16.36,5.5642,4.9749,6.1535,-8.1976,-8.5188,-7.8764
16.4,5.4815,4.7513,6.2117,-8.1132,-8.5086,-7.7179
16.44,5.4316,4.6731,6.19,-8.0414,-8.4595,-7.6233
16.48,5.4079,4.6978,6.1179,-8.0198,-8.3218,-7.7178
16.52,5.3731,4.8915,5.8547,-8.0236,-8.1053,-7.9418
16.56,5.5056,5.2508,5.7605,-8.1507,-8.3439,-7.9574
16.6,5.5714,5.3066,5.8362,-8.2214,-8.7373,-7.7054
16.64,5.5832,5.2259,5.9406,-8.2499,-8.8658,-7.6339
16.68,5.587,5.1692,6.0049,-8.2355,-8.8264,-7.6445
16.72,5.5594,5.1322,5.9865,-8.2328,-8.6869,-7.7787
16.76,5.5387,4.9824,6.0949,-8.2001,-8.6205,-7.7797
16.8,5.4439,4.7606,6.1273,-8.1231,-8.5718,-7.6744
16.84,5.358,4.6073,6.1087,-8.0344,-8.4224,-7.6464
16.88,5.3622,4.7038,6.0206,-8.025,-8.2767,-7.7733
16.92,5.3469,4.8687,5.8251,-8.0623,-8.1119,-8.0127
16.96,5.3624,5.1224,5.6024,-8.0932,-8.3935,-7.793
17,5.4389,5.2731,5.6047,-8.1905,-8.7237,-7.6573
17.04,5.4783,5.1772,5.7793,-8.2555,-8.9358,-7.5751
17.08,5.4979,5.1699,5.8258,-8.2484,-8.9139,-7.5829
17.12,5.4437,5.0455,5.8419,-8.283,-8.8392,-7.7267
17.16,5.4542,4.897,6.0114,-8.2238,-8.6675,-7.7801
17.2,5.3769,4.7225,6.0313,-8.1619,-8.6314,-7.6923
17.24,5.284,4.5999,5.968,-8.0745,-8.4358,-7.7132
17.28,5.2305,4.657,5.804,-8.0153,-8.1969,-7.8337
17.32,5.2639,4.8379,5.69,-8.0564,-8.1557,-7.9572
17.36,5.2931,5.1229,5.4634,-8.1233,-8.5252,-7.7214
17.4,5.311,5.2578,5.3642,-8.1673,-8.72,-7.6146
17.44,5.3898,5.1694,5.6101,-8.2527,-8.9228,-7.5827
17.48,5.4423,5.168,5.7167,-8.3127,-8.9051,-7.7203
17.52,5.4021,4.973,5.8312,-8.2875,-8.8092,-7.7659
17.56,5.4159,4.8505,5.9813,-8.2791,-8.7201,-7.8382
17.6,5.3436,4.6918,5.9955,-8.1967,-8.6036,-7.7899
17.64,5.2599,4.5829,5.937,-8.0494,-8.4421,-7.6566
17.68,5.153,4.4728,5.8332,-7.819,-8.1809,-7.4571
17.72,5.0653,4.4931,5.6375,-7.623,-7.9002,-7.3458
17.76,5.0361,4.5722,5.4999,-7.3615,-7.634,-7.089
17.8,4.9857,4.7507,5.2207,-7.1503,-7.4999,-6.8007
17.84,5.015,4.8164,5.2136,-7.034,-7.5023,-6.5657
17.88,5.1345,4.9011,5.368,-6.9628,-7.5209,-6.4046
17.92,5.2402,4.8995,5.581,-6.9307,-7.4582,-6.4032
17.96,5.2999,4.8594,5.7405,-6.8847,-7.3514,-6.418
18,5.3246,4.7563,5.8929,-6.7857,-7.1467,-6.4246
18.04,5.2933,4.632,5.9546,-6.619,-6.9235,-6.3145
18.08,5.2382,4.5486,5.9279,-6.5053,-6.7718,-6.2388
18.12,5.1433,4.5943,5.6924,-6.3374,-6.4974,-6.1774
18.16,5.0859,4.6652,5.5066,-6.2045,-6.324,-6.085
18.2,5.0549,4.7084,5.4014,-6.1654,-6.4726,-5.8581
18.24,5.0822,4.7502,5.4142,-6.1253,-6.6257,-5.6248
18.28,5.0888,4.7149,5.4626,-6.1201,-6.6591,-5.5811
18.32,5.0957,4.6871,5.5043,-6.121,-6.6252,-5.6168
18.36,5.1163,4.6108,5.6219,-6.1105,-6.4983,-5.7228
18.4,5.1113,4.552,5.6707,-6.1097,-6.4176,-5.8018
18.44,5.0769,4.4655,5.6882,-6.0077,-6.1584,-5.857
18.48,5.024,4.429,5.619,-5.8976,-5.9908,-5.8044
18.52,4.9433,4.379,5.5075,-5.817,-5.8561,-5.7779
18.56,4.9255,4.5078,5.3431,-5.7114,-5.8355,-5.5872
18.6,4.8675,4.5365,5.1986,-5.671,-5.9144,-5.4277
18.64,4.8916,4.542,5.2412,-5.6676,-5.9986,-5.3366
18.68,4.9136,4.5336,5.2936,-5.6689,-6.0576,-5.2802
18.72,4.9358,4.5112,5.3603,-5.6794,-6.0281,-5.3307
18.76,4.9601,4.5008,5.4194,-5.6619,-5.9478,-5.3759
18.8,4.9299,4.4391,5.4208,-5.6609,-5.8726,-5.4492
18.84,4.8939,4.391,5.3967,-5.6293,-5.8169,-5.4416
18.88,4.8567,4.3906,5.3227,-5.5642,-5.7164,-5.412
18.92,4.8081,4.3724,5.2438,-5.5031,-5.6676,-5.3386
18.96,4.7936,4.3971,5.1902,-5.4604,-5.66,-5.2608
19,4.7795,4.4653,5.0938,-5.4183,-5.6689,-5.1678
19.04,4.7744,4.5056,5.0431,-5.3854,-5.697,-5.0738
19.08,4.7699,4.508,5.0318,-5.385,-5.7493,-5.0206
19.12,4.8036,4.5167,5.0905,-5.3959,-5.6815,-5.1104
19.16,4.8459,4.4952,5.1966,-5.3865,-5.6896,-5.0833
19.2,4.818,4.4388,5.1971,-5.3842,-5.6608,-5.1077
19.24,4.8336,4.4383,5.2288,-5.3595,-5.6469,-5.0722
19.28,4.8009,4.4178,5.184,-5.3325,-5.6355,-5.0295
19.32,4.7595,4.4106,5.1084,-5.2892,-5.641,-4.9374
19.36,4.7173,4.4114,5.0231,-5.2491,-5.6541,-4.844
19.4,4.6769,4.4033,4.9505,-5.242,-5.6535,-4.8306
19.44,4.6776,4.442,4.9131,-5.211,-5.6152,-4.8068
19.48,4.6882,4.4452,4.9312,-5.2171,-5.5881,-4.8461
19.52,4.6876,4.4074,4.9677,-5.2424,-5.5984,-4.8865
19.56,4.7373,4.4447,5.0298,-5.2465,-5.558,-4.935
19.6,4.7371,4.4209,5.0534,-5.2397,-5.5585,-4.9209
19.64,4.7339,4.412,5.0559,-5.2326,-5.5612,-4.904
19.68,4.7239,4.4156,5.0321,-5.2074,-5.5627,-4.8521
19.72,4.7017,4.3925,5.011,-5.2004,-5.5351,-4.8658
19.76,4.7158,4.4064,5.0252,-5.1445,-5.5405,-4.7486
19.8,4.669,4.3757,4.9622,-5.1503,-5.5632,-4.7375
19.84,4.6676,4.3818,4.9534,-5.1346,-5.5725,-4.6966
19.88,4.6688,4.4059,4.9316,-5.131,-5.5751,-4.6868
19.92,4.6429,4.3666,4.9192,-5.1293,-5.5824,-4.6763
19.96,4.6292,4.3271,4.9313,-5.1395,-5.6057,-4.6732
20,4.6227,4.3073,4.9381,-5.127,-5.5838,-4.6702
20.04,4.6365,4.3139,4.9591,-5.1243,-5.57,-4.6787
20.08,4.6179,4.2308,5.0049,-5.2145,-5.6812,-4.7477
20.12,4.5253,4.15,4.9006,-5.1936,-5.6417,-4.7455
20.16,4.387,3.9901,4.7839,-5.1153,-5.5297,-4.7008
20.2,4.0763,3.6647,4.4879,-5.0668,-5.5119,-4.6217
20.24,3.839,3.5204,4.1576,-5.0116,-5.4439,-4.5793
20.28,3.589,3.2374,3.9406,-4.9881,-5.4315,-4.5447
20.32,3.3876,3.0685,3.7067,-4.9713,-5.4325,-4.51
}\dummydata
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
% global stuff
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0,transform shape]
\node[circle,minimum size=6pt](c-0)  at (0,0){};
\path let \p1=($(c-0.east)-(c-0.center)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}
in \pgfextra{\xdef\shadingangle{\n1}};
\end{scope}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\dummydata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownum}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX] in {1,...,\rownum}
{\ReadOutElement{\dummydata}{\X}{xm}{\tmpx}
\ReadOutElement{\dummydata}{\X}{ym}{\tmpy}
\ReadOutElement{\dummydata}{\X}{tm}{\tmpz}
\ReadOutElement{\dummydata}{\X}{tm}{\tmpRone}
\ReadOutElement{\dummydata}{\X}{tm}{\tmpRtwo} % will be ignored
%\typeout{\tmpx,\tmpy,\tmpz,\tmpRone}
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=\tmpx,transform shape]
\node[circle,minimum size=\tmpRone](c-\X)  at (\tmpy,\tmpz){};
\end{scope}
\ifnum\X=1
\else
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw let \p1=($(c-\X.center)-(c-\LastX.center)$), 
 \p2=($(c-\X.north)-(c-\X.center)$), \p3=($(c-\X.east)-(c-\X.center)$),
 \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y3,\x3)},\n3={\n1-2*\n2}
 in \pgfextra{%\typeout{theta=\n1,\n2}
 \xdef\lastang{\n3}}
 [top color=orange!20,bottom color=orange!50,shading angle=\n1+180]
 (c-\X.\n3)
 -- (c-\LastX.\n3) -- (c-\LastX.\n3+180)
 -- (c-\X.\n3+180);
\end{scope} 
\fi
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=\tmpx,transform shape]
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=\tmpRone,
top color=orange!20,bottom color=orange!50,shading angle=\shadingangle](c-\X)  at (\tmpy,\tmpz){};
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

After a few glasses of honey liquor it starts resembling a tube. ;-)

Comment: I just got this epiphany for testing the non-trivial data-sets (didn't get the ***inner*** meaning of your comment). I will update my question with a more challenging data-set in a while. (+1) for showing the initial idea.

Comment: I have updated the question with a much more complicated data-set. I hope that is sufficient ;) Sorry for the delays on the update, I had to pre-process the data to fit here :D

Comment: @Raaja Thanks! I will try to do something. At least it is conceptually interesting, not sure if anyone has computed the tangents to circles in a 3d diagram so far. I hope to find the time to solve it. (In principle it is a combination of existing tricks.)

Comment: Thanks, I will also try in the mean time. Let me know if you have some thing :)

Comment: Since, there are no answers available other than yours, I have awarded my bounty to your answer :)

Comment: @Raaja Thanks, I do not think I deserve it but I will try to find a solution soon. These days are crazy, I only have 5 minutes windows here and there, so I could not patch things together. The analytic formula [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464143/121799), which is of course trivial in the case of circles, is actually only a downgrade of a style that I wrote for this answer, but then there were unexpected difficulties when patching things together.

Comment: I also saw that solution of yours ;), but could not make a connection with this problem here. But you can take your time to answer it ;)

Comment: better to look at it on a Saturday night;)